# Dynamically Enable/Disable Submit Button BUT Without Using Blur From Input Field

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

O.K., so this is a variant from the common question of just "how to dynamically enable/disable a button when text is entered...". Because the common and easy way of doing this is creating a Focus/Blur function with jQuery, attaching to the Blur your function to check whether, when the user Blurs (clicks away from) the input field, the value of the same is blank (and, therefore, reverted back to a default) and so the button must remain disabled.

**However, as I stress in the title, I would like the status of the input field to be checked dynamically for change so that the button is enabled or disabled without the user having to click away from the input field.**

One usually fills the input field or the last input field on a form and then clicks on submit. When the responsibility of handling the enabling/disabling of the submit falls on the blur function, the user is not able to fill in the input and click straight away on the submit without it remaining disabled. A common user will think something's wrong; a more experienced user might try to click away (thereby working the Blur function) but I'm sure we all agree this is not practical, not to mention anything but elegant.

I personally think that a separate function to handle the enable/disable is much more elegant. Plus, I wasn't sure whether or not it would actually solve this issue. So I ended up trying

```
    $('input#name').change(function () {
      if (this.value.length > 0 && this.value !== default_value) {
        $('button#submit').removeProp('disabled')
      } else {
        $('button#submit').prop('disabled', 'true');
      }
    });
```

It works fine, but just in the same way the Focus/Blur function does: the "change" in the field is understood by jQuery as, basically, the focusing and blurring of the same. So, back to square one.

Does anyone out there have any idea how to work through this specific issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about keyup or keydown?

```
$('input#name').keyup(function () {
  if (this.value.length > 0 && this.value !== default_value) {
    $('button#submit').removeProp('disabled')
  } else {
    $('button#submit').prop('disabled', 'true');
  }
});
```

Comment: Simple, yet elegant, and right on the money! Thanks a lot, bbird! Now that you've given the answer it seems so obvious to me... but a couple of hours ago my mind was completely blank. Terrible when that happens...